# How to change array value depend on condition in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have array like this

```
var country = ["America","Germany","China"]
```

My need is if this array have America

I would like to make it become "US"

hoping result like this

```
["US","Europe","Asia"]
```

don't use `country[0] = "US"`

because array order every times are different

Use condition that I gave

How should I do ?

Comment: Have a look at the `map` generic function: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017520-map
You can check each element and return an appropriate replacement, generating a new, transformed array.

Comment: 1. "America" isn't really a country name, it's a common nickname for the U.S.A. 2. You map Germany and China to their corresponding continents. Why do you map "America" to US and not "North America"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it (comments inline):

```
let country = ["USA", "Germany", "China", "Fakeland"]

// use a dictionary for the replacements   
let continentForCountry = ["USA": "North America", "Germany": "Europe", "China": "Asia"]

// use map to replace each item and set a default value if the
// replacement is not found
let result = country.map { continentForCountry[$0, default: "unknown continent"] }

print(result)
```

> ```
> ["North America", "Europe", "Asia", "unknown continent"]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary of what a string in countries needs to be replaced with.

```
let countriesToRegions = ["America": "US", "Germany": "Europe", "China": "Asia"]
```

Then when you need to convert the countries into regions, you can look them up in the dictionary.

```
var countries = ["America", "Germany", "China"]

let regions = countries.map { country in
    countriesToRegions[country] ?? country
}
```

The last bit here, `?? country`, is handling the possibility that the country is not in the `countriesToRegions` dictionary.

Comment: Guessing that the OP will want to map other European countries to "Europe" and other Asian countries to "Asia", etc., it seems like it would be better to create a dictionary where the continent is the key and the value is a list of countries for that continent.

Comment: @rmaddy I like the more straightforward (if redundant mapping) `["Spain": "Europe", "Germany": "Europe", "France": "Europe", "China": "Asia", "Japan": "Asia"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
let requiredIndex = country.index(where: { $0 is "America" }) {
            country[requiredIndex] = "US"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `Map` or for a more explained version, can use the below function

```
func replaceOccuranceInArray(inArray:[String], of originalString: String, with replacementString: String) -> [String] {

   var arrayToBeReturned = inArray

   var indexes = [Int]()

   for currentIndex in 0...inArray.count - 1 {

    if inArray[currentIndex] == originalString {
         indexes.append(currentIndex)
      }

  }

  for eachIndex in indexes {
      arrayToBeReturned[eachIndex] = replacementString
  }

  return arrayToBeReturned

}
```

I have attached a *Playground output* for the same below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution :

Get the index of the value to be replaced and replace it if existing:

```
if let ind = country.firstIndex(of: "America"){
    country[ind] = "US"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As some suggested, you can use power of `.map` function.

Here is simple solution how you can map country to continent:

```
let americanCountries = ["US", "Argentina", "Brasil"]
let asianCountries = ["China", "Japan", "Korea"]
let europeanCountries = ["Germany", "France", "Spain"]

let countries = ["US","Germany","China"]

let continents = countries.map { country -> String in
    if americanCountries.contains(country) {
        return "America"
    } else if asianCountries.contains(country) {
        return "Asia"
    } else if europeanCountries.contains(country) {
        return "Europe"
    } else {
        return "Unknown continent"
    }
}
```

Another step would be try to use enums.